# Convert schema of a Spark DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark DataFrame on PySpark and I want to store its schema into another Spark DataFrame.

For example:
I have a sample DataFrame `df` that looks like -

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|                  v|
+---+-------------------+
|  0| 0.4707538108432022|
|  0|0.39170676690905415|
|  0| 0.8249512619546295|
|  0| 0.3366111661094958|
|  0| 0.8974360488327017|
+---+-------------------+
```

I can look out at the schema of `df` by doing -

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- v: double (nullable = false)
```

What I require is a DataFrame that displays above information on `df` in two columns `col_name` and `dtype`.

Expected Output:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| col_name|              dtype|
+---------+-------------------+
|       id|            integer|
|        v|             double|
+---------+-------------------+
```

How do I achieve this? I cannot find anything regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: parallelize `df.dtypes`

Comment: I got the desired result by spark.createDataFrame(df.dtypes, ["col_name", "dtypes"]). Thanks. What do you mean by parallelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be create a dataframe from `df.dtypes`:

```
spark.createDataFrame(df.dtypes, ["col_name", "dtype"]).show()
#+--------+------+
#|col_name| dtype|
#+--------+------+
#|      id|   int|
#|       v|double|
#+--------+------+
```

But if you wanted the `dtype` column to be as shown in `printSchema`, you could do so through `df.schema`

```
spark.createDataFrame(
    [(d['name'], d['type']) for d in df.schema.jsonValue()['fields']],
    ["col_name", "dtype"]
).show()
#+--------+-------+
#|col_name|  dtype|
#+--------+-------+
#|      id|integer|
#|       v| double|
#+--------+-------+
```